# Changed value in DGV not saved when main form moves to next row

Tags: database, vb.net

I have a form displaying data from a parent table one row at a time. The user moves from one row to another using the form's binding navigator. This same form also contains a DGV that displays data from a related child table. When this form is closed, it saves the data back to the source databases using the data adapters used to populate the form and the DGV.

The problem I have is if the user changes a cell on the DGV without moving to another cell or row in the DGV but simply uses the binding navigator to move to another row and then back, the change in the DGV cell is lost. How can I prevent this?

I tried changing the binding navigator's MoveNextItem property to "None" and then added the following code:

`Private Sub BindingNavigatorMoveNextItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BindingNavigatorMoveNextItem.Click`

`BSExps.EndEdit()`

`BS.MoveNext()`

Where "BSExps" is the binding source used to populate the child table and "BS" is the binding source for the parent table and binding navigator. However, this does not resolve the issue.

How can I programmatically save any changes to the DGV if the user simply moves to another row of the parent table and does not click any other cell or row in the DGV?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the "BSExps.EndEdit" to:

`Me.DataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.CurrentCellChange)`

This seems to have solved the problem, now any change to the DGV is saved when the user moves to another record and then moves back.